# Show that if an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, so is $A^k$ for some integer $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

We know that if $A$ is diagonalizable that means it is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ whose columns are the eigenvectors of the linear transformation $T$ that corresponds to $A$.

I think that this fact could somehow be used. We know that if raise a diagonal matrix to a power, the only thing that changes are the diagonal entries (because every other entry is $0$). Therefore, connecting that to the eigenvalues of $A$ I think one might be able to make some good observations and possibly prove this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first statement needs to be corrected. $A$ is diagonalizable means, $\exists \, P$ (with columns as eigenvectors....) such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. Now you can argue that $A^k=PD^kP^{-1}$.

Comment: Luka, note that the phrase "for some integer $k$" is commonly taken to mean at least one such $k$ exists (other than $1$ I guess). You probably want to write "for every (positive) integer $k\;$ "

Comment: @AnuragA I think that what you said is equivalent to what I said. A matrix being similar to a diagonal matrix means precisely that $\exists P$ which is an invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}DP$ is equal to our matrix $A$.

Comment: @WillJagy You are correct. That is what I meant and I accidentally wrote the wrong thing. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it is true that $A^k$ is diagonalizable for *every* $k \in \Bbb N$, because $A$ diagonalizable means that there is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix $S$ with

$SAS^{-1} = D, \tag 1$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix; then

$SA^kS^{-1} = (SAS^{-1})^ k = D^k, \tag 2$

and $D^k$ is diagonal since $D$ is diagonal.

In the above we used the fact that

$SA^kS^{-1} = (SAS^{-1})^ k, \tag 3$

which may easily be proved by induction on $k$; I leave this to the members of my vast audience.

Comment: Just made a couple grammatical changes in case the previous wording might have been confusing to non native English speakers.

Comment: @Shalop:  OK and thanks!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, it means it can be written as:
$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
Now multiply both sides by $A$
$$AA=PDP^{-1}A$$
$$A^2=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}$$
$$A^2=PD(P^{-1}P)DP^{-1}$$
$$A^2=PDI_nDP^{-1}$$
$$A^2=PDDP^{-1}$$
$$A^2=PD^2P^{-1}$$
Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size n.

Therefore the statement has been proven for $k=2$.
You can also prove it for an arbitrary positive integer $k$ by induction.